# Should SQLiteOpenHelper methods accept objects or IDs?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, standards

This might be more of a style / standards / practices question, but which of the following is the better way and why:

```
public long insertSomething(MyAccount account, Employee employee, double rating) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ACCOUNT_ID, account.getId());
    values.put(EMPLOYEE_ID, employee.getId());
    values.put(RATING, rating);
    return mDatabase.insert(MY_TABLE, null, values);
}
```

This is basically accepting objects and then using their IDs inside the method to perform the query.

Or:

```
public long insertSomething(long accountId, long employeeID, double rating) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ACCOUNT_ID, accountId);
    values.put(EMPLOYEE_ID, employeeID);
    values.put(RATING, rating);
    return mDatabase.insert(MY_TABLE, null, values);
}
```

Is there a reason to do one or the other? I am unsure which approach I should be going with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both implementations are equally effective, so it goes down to what is more immediate and friendly to use for you.

Sometimes effectiveness is determined by factors other than pure performance, like readability and consistency. Regarding consistency, it would be a bit easier to maintain the code if all methods in your SQLiteOpenHelper use only objects or only single values as parameters, because in the long run you get used to the general structure of the code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are putting your code in wrong place. Sure, it will technically work, but logically, `SQLOpenHelper` is, as name indicates, for different purposes. So once you properly separate the code - it depends on the purpose and on how you pass data in your app. If you use IDs mostly, then 2nd approach would fit better, if you hand objects, then the first. If mixed, then perhaps this is what you will end up with:

```
public long insertSomething(long accountId, Employee employee, double rating) {
    return insertSomething(accountId, employee.getId(), rating);
}

public long insertSomething(long accountId, long employeeID, double rating) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ACCOUNT_ID, accountId);
    values.put(EMPLOYEE_ID, employeeID);
    values.put(RATING, rating);
    return mDatabase.insert(MY_TABLE, null, values);
}
```

But perhaps you jest need to become familiar with ORM so then you'd most likely end up with (constructor could also accept Employee object, does not matternow):

```
new EmpoleeRating(accountId, employeeId, rating)
    .save();
```